# Как просуммировать данные по уникальной дате?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица, которая хранит дату, столбец по которому идёт статистика и прочие данные для группировки. Выглядит так:

```
added               | amount | groupType
2023-06-13 11:20:12 | 10     | 0
2023-06-13 11:20:12 | 10     | 0
2023-06-13 11:21:12 | 10     | 0
2023-06-13 12:20:12 | 11     | 1
2023-06-13 13:20:12 | 12     | 1
```

Код создания и заполнения таблицы:

```
# create
CREATE TABLE example (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  added datetime NOT NULL,
  amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
  groupType INTEGER not null
);

# insert
INSERT INTO example VALUES (0001, '2023-06-13 11:20:20', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO example VALUES (0002, '2023-06-13 11:20:20', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO example VALUES (0003, '2023-06-13 11:21:20', 10, 0);
INSERT INTO example VALUES (0004, '2023-06-13 12:20:20', 11, 1);
INSERT INTO example VALUES (0005, '2023-06-13 13:20:20', 12, 1);
```

В таблицу заносятся только такие значения (совпадает время, значение). Не получится вставить строку с одинаковой датой, но разным значением. (Эти поля не должны быть `unique`).

Теперь я хочу сгруппировать данные по дате и часу добавления, но получить сумму только тех элементов у которых дата уникальная. То есть так:

```
groupTime           | sumAmount | groupType
2023-06-13 11:00:00 | 20        | 0
2023-06-13 12:00:00 | 11        | 1
2023-06-13 13:00:00 | 12        | 1
```

Я использовал следующий запрос, но он выдавал неверный результат (для даты `2023-06-13 11:20:12` `amount` был `30`):

```
select cast(concat(date(added), ' ', hour(added)) as datetime) as groupTime, sum(amount) as sumAmount
from example
group by date(added), hour(added);
```

Я исправил это следующим образом:

```
select cast(concat(date(added), ' ', hour(added)) as datetime) as groupTime, sum(amount) as sumAmount
from (
select distinct added, amount
from example
) temp
group by date(added), hour(added);
```

И теперь результат выдался верным. Как вообще решаются подобные проблемы? Правильно ли я её решил и есть ли более красивые или оптимальные в плане скорости решения?
Пример в [online mysql](https://onecompiler.com/mysql/3zmx5nznk).

Comment: *но получить сумму только тех элементов у которых дата уникальная* Если штамп времени совпадает, а значение нет - что делать?

Comment: @Akina Такое не произойдёт. В таблицу заносятся только такие значения (совпадает время, значение)

Comment: Либо это поддержано соотв. средствами контроля целостности (и я плохо представляю какими именно, констрейнт не составить, триггер не справится), либо все заверения гроша ломаного не стоят...

Comment: @Akina значения `amount` могут быть любыми, кроме тех, что идут с одинаковым временем. Они одинаковые. Да и вопрос был о том, как это решается более оптимально в плане выборки, есть ли лучшее решение? Например - без подзапросов?

Comment: По вашему примеру результата, группировка должна быть сделана с приведением added к целым часам.

Comment: то есть сначала надо сделать костыль, напихав дубли строк в таблицу, а потом его пытаться решить?

Comment: @teran нет. Я же сказал, что остальные столбцы, которые `groupType` - это прочие столбцы, которые необходимы для других группировок. Из-за них и получаются дубли. И нужны все результаты сохранённые, а только для конкретно примера мне надо убирать дубли

Comment: тогда distinct как есть. альтернативно можно группировку сделать. Если это решение приемлемо по производительности, то так и делайте.  В противном случае, какие нить промежуточные таблицы нужны для хранения расчитанных данных. Если за период делаете выборку, то индекс накиньте. Если там еще куча столбцов в таблице, то может быть покрывающий индекс для этого случая, если есть потребность обеспечить максимум производительности. Заодно убедиться, что INT не избыточен в размерности для хранения этих данных.

Comment: @teran Вас понял, спасибо, что уделили время, попробую проследовать вашим рекомендациям